# Add new point to bullet points

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have question. I want to save path to the file from disk to the `<ul></ul>` under `<li></li>`.

I want to choose for example 2 files from `<import>` and get `<ul><li>1path</li><li>2path</li></ul>` and after that for example i want add 2 next files and show them in new `<li></li>` to get paths to those 4 files. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking + what have you tried so far?

Comment: You're asking if new content can be added to the page? If so, then clearly the answer is "yes". If you don't know where to begin, start here: [MDN Learn JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*<initiating bad question translator>*

> - You have an `<input type="file" multiple />` element
> - You also have a `<ul>`
> - You want it so that when a file or files are selected, they appear as items in the list.

*<Computing answer>*

Bind an event listener for the `change` event of your file input. Read the `files` property of the input element. This will be an array of files. You should then be able to get the filenames. For each filename, create a new `<li>` element, put the filename in it, and append to your list.

Give this algorithm a try, and come back with some code if you have further problems :)